# Managing Image Dimensions using Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the following image from which I have calculated the dimensions using by few preprocessing like gray scaling, noise removal, dilation, getting corners (CornerHarris), and then using distance formula to get the dimensions. Complete info regarding it can be seen in the [Previos Question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14981110) I know that the dimensions are not correct because I need a reference object to transform the size of the box. But you can see that the image is of a box so logically lengths 42, 54 and 49 must be same but they are not because the way image is taken makes the background smaller so it returns a smaller distance. Am I doing it wrong ? OR any better ideas to get those dimensions such that they are equal. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can not calculate dimensions of 3D object s from an image. (Read about projection). You will need a 3D model for getting the measurements

Comment: You need 2 cameras to be able to accuratedly see in 3D. That is one of the reasons you have 2 eyes instead of 1